# Hide rootnode in treeview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, nodes

How can I hide the rootnode in this case the "temp" folder?
I want to do this whitout setting a CssClass on the rootnode.

```
TreeView TreeView1 = new TreeView();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuildTree(@"C:\temp");
        form1.Controls.Add(TreeView1);
    }
    private void BuildTree(string root)
    {
        DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(root);
        TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(rootDir.Name, rootDir.FullName);
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
        TraverseTree(rootDir, rootNode);
    }
    private void TraverseTree(DirectoryInfo currentDir, TreeNode currentNode)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in currentDir.GetDirectories())
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dir.Name, dir.FullName);
            currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
            TraverseTree(dir, node);
        }
        foreach (FileInfo file in currentDir.GetFiles())
        {
            TreeNode nodeFile = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName);
            currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(nodeFile);
        }
    }
```

The code is complete and redy to run just change the path to your desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just not add the Root node in the first place, instead, set all the direct descendants as level 1 nodes:

```
TreeView TreeView1 = new TreeView();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildTree(@"C:\temp");
    form1.Controls.Add(TreeView1);
}
private void BuildTree(string root)
{
    DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(root);
    TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(rootDir.Name, rootDir.FullName);
    TraverseTree(rootDir, TreeView1.Nodes);
}
private void TraverseTree(DirectoryInfo currentDir, TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in currentDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dir.Name, dir.FullName);
        nodeCollection.Add(node);                
        TraverseTree(dir, node.ChildNodes);
    }
    foreach (FileInfo file in currentDir.GetFiles())
    {
        TreeNode nodeFile = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName);
        nodeCollection.Add(nodeFile);
    }
}
```

Edit: I have amended the code above to remove the `AddToNode` Method I wrote. The previous method was checking to see if the currentNode object passed in was null, and if so adding it to the NodesCollection of TreeView1 (otherwise to the ChildNodes collection of the currentNode). Instead, rather than passing the node around, I'm passing the NodeCollection of the node around - this means that we can simplify the logic a fair bit).

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I just threw this together pretty quickly, so I think it's possible to simplify the code down a touch, I'll Edit the answer to reflect the simplification.