# How to hide Root folder in TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I load the file into a file and I make a TreeView in WPF MVVM. 
When I get the UI, I do not want to see my root folder. How to do that, can anyone help me? How to hide root folder? Her is a code for treeview and for style.

> ```
> <GroupBox Margin="10" Header="DSC Configurations" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
>   Height="850" Width="500">
>      <TreeView DataContext="{Binding RootItem}"
>      Template="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplate}">
>      <TreeViewItem Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>
>  </TreeView>
> </GroupBox>
>
>   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
>         <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"/>
>         <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
>         <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" />
>         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
>         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
>     </Style>
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383391/hide-rootnode-in-treeview-asp-net

Comment: Remove the root folder and bind to a list of child folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide rootnode in treeview asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383391/hide-rootnode-in-treeview-asp-net)

Comment: Without seeing the object graph your view is bound against, no though.

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding root TreeViewItem `<TreeViewItem Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>` bind ItemsSource of TreeView:

```
 <TreeView DataContext="{Binding RootItem}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
           Template="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplate}"/>
```